# Casting unsigned char* to long

Tags: c, casting, long-integer

What does the following expression mean?

```
unsigned char *res = malloc(5);
```

Now I cast `res`:

```
(long)res
```

What does this casting mean?

Answer (score 4):

Using that value will interpret the address to which `res` points (which is just a number anyway) as a long.

It will work most of the time but it's not completely okay (depends a lot on how you're using it). For example if you simply want to print it, you can get away with

```
printf("%p", res);
```

As a rule of thumb: **treat any cast with suspicion**.

Comment: Assume `long` is 2 words, and `unsigned char*` is 1 word. Where will it take the rest of the bits? call stack?

Comment: The rest of the bits will be either 1 if the source type is signed and negative, or 0 otherwise.

Comment: and what does it mean? can you please give me an example?

Comment: why would I want to interpret the address to which res points as a long?

Answer (score 2):

The allocated memory is not read, you're just casting the pointer to the memory to a long.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but is a useful bit of information that is more-or-less relevant to your siutation.

A cast from a pointer type to an integer type is implementation defined (that means the implementation decides what happens when you cast a pointer to an integer). C99 implementations that do support some type of reversible conversion should also provide two types found in `<stdint.h>` specifically for converting pointers to integers, namely `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`. If your implementation provides these two types, then you can safely convert a pointer to these types and back to the original pointer type.

Since these types are implementation defined, you will need to check your implementations documentation for what the underlying types are.